# Get image geolocation (chosen from image picker)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, geolocation, uiimagepickercontroller

Guys I really need your help on this one.

I have been struggling for a few hours now. I have an app in which user can choose an image from an `UIImagePicker`. I need to get that image geolocation (latitude and longitude) somehow. All I could find was this http://code.google.com/p/iphone-exif/ library which is not completely free.

How can I accomplish this? Im looking for the simplest way :) If there is no other way than by using the library on the provided link, can you show me how to do it? Or direct me somewhere where this is shown?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of iOS 4.x, the [CGImageSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageSource/Reference/reference.html) API became available as a viable way to get and read the EXIF data of an image.

(Side Note: the link to the documentation is actually device agnostic, apple just doesn't write two versions for some C-interface frameworks).

Comment: Yes, thank you. Can you show me an example of reading lat and lon from an `UIImage` as well please?

Comment: [Straight from apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/ImageIOGuide/imageio_source/ikpg_source.html), code and all.  Third example down.